# How to extract data from Interface

Tags: go, redis

I am using Redigo to retrieve metrics from Redis. While the package has some built in helpers to parse the data in responses of certain formats, I have a format that I need to parse, which isn't covered.

The result of the command is type Interface and contains an array of indeterminate length, within each is a set of data. If I print the result out as a string, I get (line breaks added for readability)...

```
[
      [name cgroup1 consumers %!s(int64=2) pending %!s(int64=90) last-delivered-id 1582572156729-0] 
      [name cgroup2 consumers %!s(int64=2) pending %!s(int64=110) last-delivered-id 1582572156729-0]
]
```

How would I go about iterating through such a response in Go and accessing the data. I have found a lot of examples dealing with JSON and unmarshaling, but have found nothing similar to the above.

The redis command used was...

```
xinfo groups <stream name>
```

The data in Redis, looks like this...

```
1) 1) "name"
   2) "cgroup1"
   3) "consumers"
   4) (integer) 2
   5) "pending"
   6) (integer) 90
   7) "last-delivered-id"
   8) "1582572156729-0"
2) 1) "name"
   2) "cgroup2"
   3) "consumers"
   4) (integer) 2
   5) "pending"
   6) (integer) 110
   7) "last-delivered-id"
   8) "1582572156729-0"
```

If I print out the type it shows...

```
[]interface {}
```

The other question is how to extract information nested deeper.

For example

```
XINFO STREAM <stream name>
```

I am able to use ScanStruct to get everything from the first level, but can't seem to get the info under first-entry.

My Info struct

```
type Stream struct {
    Length int    `redis:"length"`
    Groups int    `redis:"groups"`
    LastID string `redis:"last-generated-id"`
}
```

If I try to add **first-entry** from below, I am unsure what type to use or how to get value 12[1] (1582572131616-0)

Sample Redis Output

```
127.0.0.1:6379> xinfo stream stream1
 1) "length"
 2) (integer) 1200
 3) "radix-tree-keys"
 4) (integer) 12
 5) "radix-tree-nodes"
 6) (integer) 30
 7) "groups"
 8) (integer) 2
 9) "last-generated-id"
10) "1582642828055-10"
11) "first-entry"
12) 1) "1582572131616-0"
    2) 1) "payload"
       2) "message:0"
13) "last-entry"
14) 1) "1582642828055-10"
    2) 1) "payload"
       2) "message:99"
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question what type the return value is.  Edit the question to show the Redis command that produced the result. The return types for each command are well documented.

Comment: It looks like the result is `[][]interface` (or `[]interface` where each element is `[]interface`), and the elements of the array are strings or `int64`s. You can descend down the structure using a series of type-assertions and get the data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [redis.Values](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Values) to convert `interface{}` to slices.  Use [redis.ScanStruct](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#ScanSlice) to set struct fields from a slice of name-value pairs.

```
type Group struct {
    Name            string `redis:"name"`
    Consumers       int    `redis:"consumers"`
    Pending         int    `redis:"pending"`
    LastDeliveredID string `redis:"last-delivered-id"`
}

func scanGroups(resp interface{}, err error) ([]*Group, error) {
    // Get slice from resp
    groups, err := redis.Values(resp, err)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var result []*Group

    // For each group
    for _, g := range groups {

        // Get slice for group
        v, err := redis.Values(g, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // Scan slice to struct
        var group Group
        err = redis.ScanStruct(v, &group)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // Accumlate result
        result = append(result, &group)
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

Use it like this:

```
 groups, err := scanGroups(conn.Do("XINFO", "GROUPS", "mystream"))
```

Comment: This worked great for the XINFO GROUPS command. I ran into something a bit different in the XINFO STREAM <stream name> command, as it has more data nested below. I added further info above.